# Spring boot application - Tomcat deployment

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, web-deployment

I'm having problems deploying my spring boot application to tomcat, although works well from my IDE.
I followed the instructions from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

But as a result I got a war package containing only framework libs and web classes, nothing from my core module.

I'm not sure if my pom files are correct.

Structure of my project look like that:

```
portal  
   -web 
     -src
     pom1.xml
   -core  
     -src  
     pom2.xml  
pom0.xml
```

project pom (pom0.xml):

```
<modules>
    <module>core</module>  
    <module>web</module>
    <module>tests</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

web module pom (pom1.xml):

```
 <parent>
    <artifactId>portal</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.portal</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

core module pom (pom2.xml)

```
 <parent>
    <artifactId>portal</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.portal</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>core</artifactId>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.custom.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

UPDATE1

More detailed structure:

```
-web  
  -com.portal.web 
   -controller  
    IncidentController  
    ComputerController
    ...  
-core  
 -com.portal.core  
   -domain  
    Incident  
    Computer  
    ...
```

mvn clear package gives that error:

```
[INFO] portal ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.700 s]  
[INFO] core ............................................... SUCCESS [  2.478 s]  
[INFO] web ................................................ FAILURE [  0.458 s]  
[INFO] tests .............................................. SKIPPED  
...  
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project web: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:  
[ERROR] /.../portal/web/src/main/java/com/portal/web/controller/IncidentController.java:[4,37] package com.portal.core.domain does not exist  
[ERROR] /.../portal/web/src/main/java/com/portal/web/controller/IncidentController.java:[5,38] package com.portal.core.service does not exist  
[ERROR] /.../portal/web/src/main/java/com/portal/web/controller/IncidentController.java:[18,19] cannot find symbol  
[ERROR] symbol:   class IIncidentService  
[ERROR] location: class com.portal.web.controller.IncidentController  
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for multi module project is to configure Boot's repackaging to apply a classifier to the jar:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Full description of the problem is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6792)

Answer (score 0):

Add the "web module" to the modules section of the parent "portal module":

```
<modules>
  <module>core</module>
  <module>api</module>
  <module>tests</module>
  <module>web</module>
</modules>
```

Run `mvn clean package`in the folder of the parent "portal module".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was a typo, module web exists in modules of the parent folder. I updated my question of the error I got after executing mvn clean package.